# Using JQuery to add metadata in the Head Tag

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to insert a new meta tag within the Head, I'm using a content managment system that won't allow editing within the Head so I'm attempting to do this using jQuery.  Unfortunately I can't it to work.

This is the code I've added to the following webpage: http://www.newcastlegateshead.com

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$("head").append("<meta name=viewport content=width=400, initial-scale=0.45, minimum-    scale=0.45/><link rel=apple-touch-icon href=/images/customIcon.png/><meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-capable content=no /><meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style content=black-translucent /><link rel=apple-touch-icon-precomposed href=/images/customIcon.png/> ");
</script>
```

Comment: Try spreading the multiple `<meta>` tags over multiple `append` calls.

Comment: @user1419007 NO NO NO NO NO do not do that. Never access the dom more often than you need to!

Comment: You are missing the `$(document).ready(...)` wrapper needed for jQuery. See @thecodeparadox's answer.

Comment: THX I've added wrapper but its still not working: 
    <script type="text/javascript"> $(function() {$("head").append("<meta name=viewport content=width=400, initial-scale=0.45, minimum-scale=0.45/><link rel=apple-touch-icon href=/images/customIcon.png/><meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-capable content=no /><meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style content=black-translucent /><link rel=apple-touch-icon-precomposed href=/images/customIcon.png/> ");}); </script>

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try your code within

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $("head").append("<meta name=viewport content=width=400, initial-scale=0.45, minimum-    scale=0.45/><link rel=apple-touch-icon href=/images/customIcon.png/><meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-capable content=no /><meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style content=black-translucent /><link rel=apple-touch-icon-precomposed href=/images/customIcon.png/> ");
    });
</script>
```

Short form of `$(document).ready(function() {...})` is:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // Your code
})
```

This will ensure that you code will execute during [`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload).

Comment: Hi tried that still not working?
'code'<script type="text/javascript">       $(document).ready(function() {          $("head").append("<meta name=viewport content=width=400, initial-scale=0.45, minimum-    scale=0.45/><link rel=apple-touch-icon href=/images/customIcon.png/><meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-capable content=no /><meta name=apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style content=black-translucent /><link rel=apple-touch-icon-precomposed href=/images/customIcon.png/> ");     }); </script>

[link](http://www.newcastlegateshead.com)

Comment: @Yippyj if you have firebug then open it's `console` after page load and execute your above code and then inspect you dom, you'll find your newly added meta tags

Comment: @thecodeparadox does that affect seo since its not showing in view source but showing in console

Answer (score 0):

[@thecodeparadox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/690854/thecodeparadox)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11018691/6045800) almost worked for me. To get it to work I needed single quotes **not** double quotes before and after `<meta>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $("head").append('<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">');
     });
</script>
```