# Set dynamic Meta Tags and Open Graph tags using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to add dynamic tags using jQuery but it seems not to work. I load my script directly after loading the page.

This is my `HTML`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is how I add the tags on jQuery.

```
$(function() {
      $('head').append('<meta property="og:type" content="profile"/>'); 
      $('head').append('<meta property="og:url" content=""/>');
      $('head').append("<meta property='og:title' content="+text+"'/>");
      $('head').append("<meta property='og:image' content="+imageUrl+"'/>");
  });
```

Why I'm doing this? After the user is visiting the page `example.com/?link=HDI635`
I would like to present a small overview of the content. So I make a API call using `jQuery` after that I would like to add the values from the API response to the Open Graph tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using JQuery to add metadata in the Head Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018638/using-jquery-to-add-metadata-in-the-head-tag)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the purpose of your tags is for generating content previews on sites like Facebook, then using jQuery will probably not work because most web crawlers do not run JavaScript, they simply just download the HTML and read it as it is.

For it to work correctly, you would need to generate the tags on server side.

You can debug your tags using Facebook's sharing debugger:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 3):

As Alan stated, most web crawlers do not run JavaScript, they simply just download the HTML and read it as it is. As of today, FB crawler doesn't.

A good solution for this is having a server (nginx is enough) to detect the User Agent of the visitor and if it is Facebook's UA (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler/) serve a simple HTML with the OG tags. Else, serve the web-app.

Answer (score 1):

You can update meta tags with JavaScript like that:

```
const title = "your title;
const description = "your description";
$('meta[name="description"]').attr('content', description);
$('meta[property="og:title"]').attr('content', title);
$('meta[property="og:description"]').attr('content', description);
// etc.
```

Google DOES read and run JavaScript stuff and it does at least read the meta-name-tags. See https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/javascript-seo-basics