# Facebook shared page doesn't have thumbnail when I have dynamically created opengraph tags in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, thumbnails, facebook-opengraph

I have an angularJS app which has a page with news articles and the articles can be shared using the Facebook sharer opened in a new window (like http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://..................). I have all required og tags for getting page title,description and thumbnail but yet the resulted post on the storyline doesn't have the thumbnail that I provide (it just has the default placeholder image for a thumbnail). The og tags are being added asynchronously to the page which introduces some milliseconds latency before the tags actually appear.

I added more image-related tags which are considered optional like  og:image:width, og:image:height, og:image:type and og:image:alt but yet the issue still exists. I've even tried waiting for a day with the hope that after facebook resets the cache I will see a normal image.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="........................">
<meta property="og:description" content="........................">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://.........................jpg">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://........................">
<meta name="description" content="........................">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="........................">
<meta property="og:locale" content="bg-BG">
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="........................">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1920">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="700">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
```

I've intentionally replaced the text with dots for the example. All the tags above were dynamically generated by the javascript code which is part of a custom AngularJS service that injects them. When I use the browser inspect tool I can clearly see all these tags but facebook's opengraph doesn't seem to see them and it's clearly indicated in the results that I get from their debug tool. The debug tool says that I'm missing tags like og:url, og:type, og:title and og:image while in reality they exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set dynamic Meta Tags and Open Graph tags using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44241258/set-dynamic-meta-tags-and-open-graph-tags-using-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4 - Update Meta tags dynamically for Facebook (Open graph)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45262719/angular-4-update-meta-tags-dynamically-for-facebook-open-graph)